# Microsoft Internal property - This property does not have a setter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ilspy

I was perusing some **System** classes with ILSpy when I came across this from the `System.Internal.HandleCollector` class:

```
internal sealed class HandleCollector
{        
    ... bunch of stuff removed ...

    internal static event HandleChangeEventHandler HandleAdded
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add
        {
            HandleCollector.HandleAdded = (HandleChangeEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(HandleCollector.HandleAdded, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove
        {
            HandleCollector.HandleAdded = (HandleChangeEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(HandleCollector.HandleAdded, value);
        }
    }
    ... bunch of stuff removed ...
}
```

How is it that Microsoft can compile this when VisualStudio complains (I copied the class) that the property doesn't have a setter?  Can someone break-down why this works yet my copy of VS complains (build flag?)?

> This property does not have a setter

The error is on each of the `HandleCollector.HandleAdded =` statements.

Comment: This is not a property; it is an `event`. Therefore it doesn't need a `get` `nor a `set` accessor.

Comment: Then why is VS complaining

Comment: ILSpy and other tools often have to struggle to represent something that doesn't directly map to the language...

Comment: @MarkGravell That would be the best explanation I've heard yet.

Comment: @ChuckSavage: On 2nd thought, I'd have to agree with Marc. That C# code is actually incorrect. It is a bit like defining a property `Foo { get { return Foo; } }`, i.e. trying to define a property without a backing field. I'd say ILSpy has produced incorrect C# code.

Comment: Ok, instead of deleting this thread as it is incorrect, I've added the ilspy tag to it, maybe someone from there will pick it up and fix it.  Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need to guess what the MS source code is because it is available [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx).

This is the declaration of `HandleAdded` from HandleCollector.cs:

```
internal static event HandleChangeEventHandler HandleAdded;
```

It is an auto-implemented event. The problem is with ILSpy's decompilation. Perhaps you should file a bug.

Comment: That is exactly what I get, at lest with ILSpy 2.1.0.1603 and .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to compile with an assignment int the add and remove implementations you need to use a field.

Like this:

```
internal sealed class HandleCollector
{
    private static HandleChangeEventHandler HandleAddedField;

    internal static event HandleChangeEventHandler HandleAdded
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        add
        {
            HandleCollector.HandleAddedField = (HandleChangeEventHandler)Delegate.Combine(HandleCollector.HandleAddedField, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        remove
        {
            HandleCollector.HandleAddedField = (HandleChangeEventHandler)Delegate.Remove(HandleCollector.HandleAddedField, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jens, but this is Microsoft code - You could suggest that to them... Anyway, we figure it is the disassembler that is faulty for giving the code I posted.

Comment: @Chuck, actually when I use ILSpy what I got was this `internal static event HandleChangeEventHandler HandleAdded;` so it's probably a bug with ILSpy.

Comment: @ChuckSavage: No, it is not Microsoft code. It is ILSpy-produced C# code generated for a Microsoft assembly (containing CIL bytecode). And something must have gone wrong in the translation from bytecode to C#.